# How to define different member function with enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, traits

My code is:

```
template<int s>
struct C{
    typename std::enable_if<s == 1, int>::type
    fun(){std::cout<<"fun1";}
    typename std::enable_if<s == 2, int>::type
    fun(){std::cout<<"fun2";}
};

int main() {
    C<1> c;
    c.fun();
}
```

The compiler said:

```
error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
```

my compiler is g++ 4.1.2 if use `template<int t = s>` before function, it will warn that is C++11 feature. I want to know how to solve that without using C++11?

Comment: 4.1.2? Why are you stuck with a compiler that's over 9 years old?

Comment: 4.1.2 Does not support c++11 features see here https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: @JerryCoffin A lot of former code is based on the compiler. We can't change it.

Comment: @bruffalobill Are there any other method to do that?

Comment: @maple Do you have access to the former source code??

Comment: @maple there is a solution to your issue that I use regularly because which can be achieved using `std::is_same` which also requires c++11 however the implementation can be added to your source easily enough without the need for c++11. Not sure how enable_if is implemented.

Comment: Just a suggestion though, you could update your compiler. Then recompile your old source files to object files using the flag `std=c++03` or `std=c++98` for backwards compatibility, then you could compile your new files using the `std=c++11` then link your object files using either `g++` directly or using `ld`??

Comment: Anyway, this code would have not worked even with a compiler that supports C++11. Just try it.

Comment: @bruffalobill Could you please explain it to me, how to do that? I can implement a enable_if because it is simple. But I don't know how to deal with my problem: define different member function depend on the given template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to implement the `enable_if` trait, you can rearrange your code as it follows (minimal, complete example) to have it working:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

struct C {
    template<int s>
    typename std::enable_if<s == 1, int>::type
    fun() { std::cout<<"fun1"; }

    template<int s>
    typename std::enable_if<s == 2, int>::type
    fun() { std::cout<<"fun2"; }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.fun<1>();
}
```

Your version (almost identical to the following one) won't work even using C++11 features, because it is not a SFINAE resolution of the name `fun`:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template<int s>
struct C {
    typename std::enable_if<s == 1, int>::type
    fun() { std::cout<<"fun1"; }
    typename std::enable_if<s == 2, int>::type
    fun() { std::cout<<"fun2"; }
};

int main() {
    C<1> c;
    c.fun();
}
```

If you want the class to be instantiated like `C<1>`, simply SFINAE isn't the way to go this time.
Please, note that `s` is known at compile time where you decide to use the template class, so you can use it whenever you want.
It follows a possible solution:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template<int s>
struct C {
    void fun() {
        if(s == 1) {
            std::cout<<"fun1";
        } else if(s == 2) {
            std::cout<<"fun2";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    C<1> c;
    c.fun();
}
```

Another solution would be possible using partial specialization, like the following one:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template<int s>
struct C;

template<>
struct C<1> {
    void fun() { std::cout<<"fun1"; }
};

template<>
struct C<2> {
    void fun() { std::cout<<"fun2"; }
};

int main() {
    C<1> c;
    c.fun();
}
```

Which one is the right one for you mainly depends on the actual problem, so I cannot say, but at least now you have several solutions from which to choice.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm sorry to forget place the main function. I edited the cod and I want it be invoked like that. Can you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even if I wouldn't suggest this approach, it follows another possible solution.
I add it as a separate answer only for the sake of curiosity, because I find the other answer most suitable.
Anyway, this one can be of interest because it shows how to use *sfinae* and function resolution to solve such an issue.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

template<int s>
struct C {
    template<int i>
    typename std::enable_if<i == 1>::type
    fun(){std::cout<<"fun1"<<std::endl;}

    template<int i>
    typename std::enable_if<i == 2>::type
    fun(){std::cout<<"fun2"<<std::endl;}

    void fun() {
        fun<s>();
    }
};

int main() {
    C<1> c1;
    c1.fun();
    C<2> c2;
    c2.fun();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to implement `std::enable_if` as mentioned in the comments, I have an alternative shown below. The solution relies on the compiler to optimize out the switch statement, however will still work with a non-optimizing compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int s>
struct C {
  int fun() {
    switch (s) {
      case 1:
        fun1();
        break;
      case 2:
        fun2();
        break;
      default:
        assert(0);
    }
  }

  inline int fun1() { std::cout << "fun1"; }
  inline int fun2() { std::cout << "fun2"; }
};
```

**Edit:** I had a look through the source code for `#include <type_traits>` and found the template for `std::enable_if` this is shown below. GPL license applies. From `g++` source code, not my own work. I would recommend combining this with skypjacks answer and you most likely solve your problem.

```
// Primary template.
/// Define a member typedef @c type only if a boolean constant is true.
template<bool, typename _Tp = void>
  struct enable_if 
  { };

// Partial specialization for true.
template<typename _Tp>
  struct enable_if<true, _Tp>
  { typedef _Tp type; };
```